# On the use of “technique” as a mass noun

Tags: uncountable-nouns, historical-change

The following passage appears in the preface to the first edition of P. Morse’s *Vibration and Sound* (1936).

> The vacuum tube and the other applications of electronics have provided immensely powerful tools for the measurement, recording, and reproduction of sound; tools which have revolutionized acoustic technique.

The word **technique** is apparently being used as a mass noun, though my intuition is that in today’s American English such a usage is not common. Would someone care to discuss on the mass/noun status of this noun in different dialects of English during different time periods, or provide a general discussion of historical changes between mass/count status?

I have made no effort to consult readily available reference works in order to answer my question before posting here.

Comment: Two points. 1. You are likely to find *XXX technique* very commonly used among musicians. In fact among guitarists you might even see *acoustic technique* used exactly as above, but of course referring to how one uses one's fingers. 2. This really looks like an editorial error. No way of knowing, but in context the word "technology" would fit perfectly.

Comment: This is not an editorial error. It is how musicians describe the discipline of playing an instrument. Sometimes it is referred to as [technic](http://mclellandpiano.homestead.com/Preface.html), and the use of *technique* may derive from that. But as someone who spent many long years practicing instruments, I can tell you that "technique" is a term used freely in that world. It is analogous grammatically to words like *strength* or *facility* or *skill*, etc.

Comment: @Robusto True: I hadn't considered that this might actually be referring to a revolution in musician's technique caused by changes in technology. Perhaps more context would help.

Comment: I agree with Robusto, and it also applies to other "crafts". By the way, isn't "uncountable" a more appropriate term here than "mass noun", even though they are no doubt meant to encompass the same set of nouns? In other words, *technique* is uncountable here, but not really a "mass".

Comment: You hear it all the time when watching the Olympics.  The talking heads often describe a gymnast as, "She has great technique."

Comment: good example, @oosterwal. I found one along those lines in COCA: *Tell us whose voice gives you the shivers just for its sheer beauty, or who has jaw-dropping **technique** or what voice has the power to wake you up in the morning and get you through a lousy day, or give you comfort or beauty or joy.* also: *I took it while at the Baltimore Conference. It is a picture of the White House taken through the fence with a VERY cheap, old digital camera and it turned out great (of course I don't know anything about photographic **technique**)!*

Comment: @Cerberus: I would hesitate to call music a "craft"; it was one of the fine arts (and the *quadrivium*, to medieval scholars). Now, English grammar—there's a craft. Part of the *trivium*, from which we get trivia (as well as this bit of trivia, as well you know).

Comment: @Robusto: Hence the quotation marks!

Comment: What is the final disclaimer supposed to mean? ***“I have made no effort to consult readily available reference works in order to answer my question before posting here.”*** Isn’t that being naughty?

Comment: @tchrist you know, just testing the site policy ;-)

Comment: @jlovegren: Love it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word is not exactly being used as a "mass noun" as you contend.

It is used in reference to a field of activity/ a discipline/ a body of knowledge/ a practice.

*Acoustic technique* here implies the practice of "measurement, recording, and reproduction of sound."

See example for the distinction between *technique*, the discipline, and *techniques*, the individual methods: [note the emphasis, mine]

> *Acoustic **Technique** 101: Alternate tunings, using a capo and travis picking*
>   Guitarist November 21, 2012, 9:30 GMT
>   If you want to play the acoustic guitar effectively, then it’s worth adding some extra basic **techniques** and approaches to how you would play your electric guitar.

Answer (score 0):

• [mass noun] skill or ability in a particular field: he has excellent technique | [in singular] : an established athlete with a very good technique.

Comment: This might be a good answer if the source of the information were cited, Without citations, any information is just opinion.. Consider editing this answer, and include your source.