# 'the computation' or 'the computations'?

Tags: grammatical-number

See this sentence

> The ***computation*** of strains, stresses and axial forces in the bar elements is straightforward.

Why not use ***computations*** here? I think since there are several different types of items mentioned after the preposition 'of', it makes more sense to use 'computations' instead of the singular form. In practice, especially in academic writing, how to determine whether use 'the + singular-form noun' or 'the + plural-form noun'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On the use of “technique” as a mass noun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121032/on-the-use-of-technique-as-a-mass-noun) (and many other questions addressing the availability of both count and noncount usages with various nouns).

Answer (score 0):

In this example, it appears the "computation" in question is a single one that is the product of multiple inputs so it makes sense to me that that this is a singular computation.  According to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation), a computation follows a well-defined model, in that way it appears to be more like a process (has a start and end).

In this book, [Models of Computation](https://cs.brown.edu/people/jsavage/book/pdfs/ModelsOfComputation.pdf), the plural is used fairly often when referencing multiple processes or multiple models.

> It is not known whether all polynomial-time computations can be done in logarithmic space. (Savage, 130)

Answer (score 0):

The formal answer from @Asks, and an answer disguised as a comment, expressed the view that the word computation was singular because the “strains, stresses and axial forces” could be considered as some sort of single unified concept. The latter may be the case in this instance, but it is *not*, in my opinion, the explanation.

I suggest this is just an example of a list in which a repeating term has been omitted for style. In this case it equates to:

> The *computation* of strains, the *computation* of stresses and the
> *computation* of axial forces is…

This allows of a situation in which a single computation gives information about many strains, but a separate computation may be required for the stresses, and another for axial forces.

This is more usual, perhaps with abstract nouns such as *computation* here, where the plurals are less common. For example, choosing an example with more disparate objects, e.g.

> The *price* of bedknobs, broomsticks and broccoli *is* subject to market
> forces.

In this case the plural might be equally common:

> The *prices* of bedknobs, broomsticks and brown paper bags *are* subject to market
> forces.

But if we replace price with, say, design, the singular would seem more natural:

> The *design* of bedknobs, broomsticks and brown paper bags *requires* skilled individuals.

Answer (score 0):

I think that "computation" in the first example is a noun referring to a course of action, while "computations" could refers to separate acts of "computation" carried out multiple times. Incidentally, both "computation" and "computations" can also refer to the results of that action or actions in question, in addition to the act of producing that result.

It would not be incorrect to say: "The computations of the strains, the stresses, and the axial forces in the bar elements are straightforward." But the singular is a more elegant way to say it.